# read() fill the buffer with extra characters

Tags: c, io, system-calls

I'm coding a simple program that read a file (filled with a random letter repeated a random number of time) 1024 bytes by 1024 bytes and send it in a FIFO pipe.
First, if my file has a size of 2007B, the first read(fdFile, buffer_f, 1024) read for example 1020B correctly, and 4 last will be random char like ?qR?.
Then, on the second read, the returned value is 983 as it should, but the buffer contains the absolute same string than before of size 1024. 
Someone knows why plz?
The same thing happen when I then read from my FIFO, but with a different random substring at the end.

```
while((buffer_f_size = read(fdFile, buffer_f, 1024)) > 0){
    printf("Partida leida en el archivo arg : \n%s\nTamano de la partida : %d\n", buffer_f, buffer_f_size);
    fflush(stdout);


    if(write(fdprox, buffer_f, buffer_f_size) != buffer_f_size){
        perror("Error en la lectura/escritura del archivo en el FIFO_proxy");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

[Part of the execution concerned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utmlS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer passed to `printf` does not necessarily have a null terminator.

You should pass the maximum number of bytes to print from the buffer:

```
while ((buffer_f_size = read(fdFile, buffer_f, 1024)) > 0) {
    printf("Partida leida en el archivo arg :\n"
           "%.*s\n"
           "Tamano de la partida : %d\n",
           (int)buffer_f_size, buffer_f, (int)buffer_f_size);
    fflush(stdout);

    if (write(fdprox, buffer_f, buffer_f_size) != buffer_f_size) {
        perror("Error en la lectura/escritura del archivo en el FIFO_proxy");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Note that if the buffer received contains null bytes, whatever contents following the first null byte will be ignored by `printf()`.

Comment: Perfect, I get it. Just something else, an other program (the server) read from the FIFO, store the result in a tmpfile to wait in order to have the whole file before writing it on the stdout. Each time a block (still of 1024B) is read, it increment a variable for the total size. When the file is completely in the tmpfile, the server read it in one block of size size_total and rewrite it on stdout. But with the result I get, it seems that only the first block read is in the tmpfile and the rest of the characters (size_total - 1024) are again random char.

Comment: @RomainArtru: you might have the same problem on the server side. It is a classic bug in client server communications to assume null termination.  Use `fwrite()` instead of `printf()` or `fputs()` to output buffer contents.

Comment: I actually used : `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer_f, size_total)`

Comment: @RomainArtru: you write `size_total` bytes in one shot, but the block is only 1024 bytes? It is hard to tell the exact bug without the complete source code.

Comment: well I first read size_total from my tmp hence they should be that number of char no ?

Comment: Is the buffer large enough to read `size_total` bytes into? Did you dump the contents of the tmpfile? Did you close the tmpfile before reopening it in read mode? Or maybe do you use RDWR mode?  Did you erase or truncate the tmpfile and/or the output file before writing to it?  There are many ways this can go wrong, you may ask a separate question if none of these hints help you locate the problem.